# Solving $2y''-y'-y=2e^x$ by variation of parameters.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find a mistake on my solution by variation of parameters of this equation:

$2y''-y'-y=2e^x$

$2m^2-m-1=0$

$m = 1, m=-\frac12$

$y_c(x) = c_1e^{x}+c_2e^{-x/2}$

$W = \begin{vmatrix} e^{x} & e^{-x/2} \\ e^{x} & -\frac{e^{-x/2}}{2}\end{vmatrix}=-\dfrac{e^{x/2}}{2}-e^{x/2}=-\dfrac{3e^{x/2}}{2}$

$W_1 = \begin{vmatrix} 0 & e^{-x/2} \\ 2e^x & -\frac{e^{-x/2}}{2}\end{vmatrix}=-2e^{x/2}$

$W_2 = \begin{vmatrix} e^{x} & 0 \\ e^{x} & 2e^{x}\end{vmatrix}=2e^{2x}$

$u_1'(x) = \dfrac{W_1}{W} = \dfrac{4}{3} \implies u_1(x) = \dfrac{4x}{3}$

$u_2'(x) = \dfrac{W_2}{W} = -\dfrac{4e^{3x/2}}{3} \implies u_2(x) = -\dfrac{8e^{3x/2}}{9}$

$y_p(x) = \dfrac{4xe^x}{3} -\dfrac{8e^{3x/2}e^{-x/2}}{9}$

$y(x) = c_1e^x + c_2e^{-x/2} +\dfrac{4xe^x}{3} -\dfrac{8e^{3x/2}e^{-x/2}}{9}$

$y(x) = c_1e^x + c_2e^{-x/2} +\dfrac{4xe^x}{3} -\dfrac{8e^{x}}{9}$

$y(x) = c_3e^x + c_2e^{-x/2} +\dfrac{4xe^x}{3}$

But the solution is:

$y(x) = c_3e^x + c_2e^{-x/2} +\dfrac{2xe^x}{3}$

Comment: I am unfamiliar with your notation, but it seems to me that if you repeated the process for the DE $y''-\frac{1}{2}y'-\frac{1}{2}y=e^{x}$ you'd get the right answer I think. So I suggest you check out what your book gives as definition of $W$ and $W_1$. Anyway it seems to me a very complicated way to use variation of parameters.

Comment: Check conditions,when can you use Variation of  parameter method.

Comment: That was my mistake indeed. I am supposed to make the leading coefficient equal to $1$ before applying the method. Thank you very much. By the way, the book is A First Course in Differential Equations with Modeling Applications by Dennis Zill.

If you wish, you can put this comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ancientmathematician and @TheStudent commented, the mistake was in the conditions of the method of variation of parameters, where the leading coefficient of the ode should be 1, and I applied the method where it is 2.